# Host MVC application in an existing site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I am already running a site where there are webforms and classic asp running concurrently. Now I have created a new project with MVC and trying to upload it to the site. I have published it in my local and uploaded files to site. But when I am trying to ping the url if says 404(file not found).

Comment: Try restarting the server in the site.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get exact problem please add the following to your web.config under

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
```

...

Then come back with your problem.